# How can i add custom fields in prestashop 1.7.6 newsletter form?

Tags: prestashop-1.7, newsletter

i need funneling the subscriptions in my 1.7.6 Prestashop newsletter. I should add custom fiels in newsletter registration form. How can i do this?
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use Module for creating new custom field. Because you are going to create also new table in the database as well. Then using the front controller to add new field.

You can read the official docs here:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/